# Tutorial on using Advanced Sharing (instead of Simple Sharing) on Windows XP and 7

Tags: networking, security, windows-xp, windows-7, network-share

We've always used Simple File Sharing. But I'm having some network difficulties with a new Windows 7 PC and I'm thinking we should be using Advanced Sharing. But as I got into it I realized it's far more complicated than I thought.

For example:

- Guest account apparently isn't included in the Everyone acccount.
- I'm not sure how to add users to a particular account (like adding Guest to Everyone) or
- How to give permission to access a folder to User X. (I tried using Permissions in Advanced Sharing and ComputerName\userName  and just UserName (obviously using the real names ) but got an error that "Name not found"

So I'm looking for a good step by step tutorial.
Free online resources are great (cheap and fast) but a book (or paid PDF download) would be OK too if it's good.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one resource that looks good:

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1334091